# Graceful Page Loading / Controlling File Loading

Tags: image, queue, loading, pageload

I am a scriptmonkey working with a lot of graphic designers who know not a thing about the web.

Despite my objections I frequently find myself with problems such as a 100Kb background image, several textual items they have made into glossy images, and 3 separate lengthy FLVs loading into a page etc etc.

I would really like to define a stack to control the flow of items loading.  Eg, render the background, then the HTML, then the page images, then load the FLVs.

I assume this exists and I have been searching badly.

Can anyone point me to good resources on this?

Answer (score 0):

For the images you can use the **load** event of the images to know when they are done. So you can chain loading this way. Look this: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5214317.html